# Efficient to sum all columns per row?

Tags: postgresql

I have been using pandas (python library) to modify some data that I take from one database (MS SQL) and load it to another one for reporting (Postgres).

One of the steps sums up a pretty large list of columns (40+) and if the result is > 0, that row is retained, otherwise it is dropped. This all takes place in memory in a pandas dataframe. This reduces the row count by 80%.

```
dimension1, ..., dimension20, count1, count2, ..., count89, count90
```

What is the best way to accomplish this using pure SQL? Can I do it directly from the SELECT query, or do I need to load everything into a temporary table (perhaps) and then only insert the rows which sum up to > 0?

Comment: `SELECT` .. from what table? What is your actual data source? A CSV file or a table in the DB? What are the data types? Cant there be NULL values? Negative values? Your Postgres version?

Comment: Select from MS SQL (raw replication source). Destination is a Postgres 10 table. All values of columns that I would sum from the source are not null integers with no negative values.